# Chamando função sem conhecimento da assinatura

Tags: c

Se eu tenho um funcão chamada calculadora() em C. E eu quero chamar essa função, obviamente eu chamaria ela pelo o nome, ou seja, pela a assinatura dela. Mas se eu não sei a assinatura dessa função, e a assinatura dela se encontrar em uma variavel do tipo char, como eu poderia chamar essa função? ou seja, tirar o nome da função armazenada na variavel do tipo char, e chamar a função.

Alguma sugestão?

Agradeço

Comment: Qual é o *problema* que você quer resolver? Mais importante, qual é a arquitetura (processador, sistema operacional, compilador) em que você está trabalhando?

Comment: O problema é esse descrito acima, é um programa em linguagem C, eu preciso chamar um função x, mas não sei o nome dela, ou seja, a assinatura. Eu vou receber o nome dessa função em uma variavel y que é uma string contendo o nome da função, como eu poderia chamar a função x com essa variavel y me informando o nome da função?

Comment: Essa é a _solução_ que você pensou pro seu problema. Esfregar dois palitinhos pra fazer fogo é a _solução_ pro _problema_ de tornar os alimentos mais nutritivos e saborosos; outra _solução_ é um forno microondas, que em muitas circunstâncias é uma solução mais prática e eficiente.

Depois que você conseguir chamar a função (e pegar o resultado dela), você vai usar isso pra fazer o quê? Se você explicar o _problema_ que você quer resolver, talvez eu consiga te dar uma _solução_ que funciona dentro dos recursos e das limitações do C.

Comment: Eu não espero um resultado da função, isso não importa, o unico problema é chamar a função. Pode ser uma função do tipo INT que retorne 0 apenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael,

A linguagem C não suporta esse tipo de operação. O que você pode fazer é compilar uma dll com as funções e depois pesquisar a função pelo nome dentro da dll.

Exemplo

```
#include <Windows.h>
HANDLE funcoes;
int (*teste)(int);

funcoes = LoadLibrary("funcoes.dll");

if(funcoes>(void*)HINSTANCE_ERROR){
      teste = GetProcAddress(funcoes, nomedafuncao);
      teste(5);
}
```

Comment: Nunca programei DLL's, mas quando eu passo o nome da função em GetProcAddress ele chama a função diretamento, ou dentro da DLL eu faz uma serie de IF's para achar a função?

Comment: A função GetProcAddress retorna o endereço da função dentro da DLL pesquisando diretamente pelo nome, que pode ser uma variável.

Comment: Em qual biblioteca esta declarada essa função? Outra coisa, no linux é possivel também fazer a leitura dessas DLL's?

Comment: A biblioteca para linux é dlfcn.h. Sim, porém a sintaxe é diferente, utilizará dlopen para abrir (utiliza flags, vide documentação) e dlsym para encontrar o nome da função dentro da dll.

Para mais informações desta biblioteca para linux entre neste link:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html

Answer (score 1):

Sugestão: mostra o teu código.
Eu mostro o meu :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int (*fx_t)(int); /* fx_t e ponteiro para funcao que recebe e devolve int */

int fx1(int a) { return a + 1; }
int fx2(int a) { return a + 2; }
int fx3(int a) { return a + 3; }

int main(void) {
    char y[10];
    strcpy(y, "fx2"); /* obtem y do utilizador */

    fx_t x = NULL;
    if (strcmp(y, "fx1") == 0) x = fx1;
    if (strcmp(y, "fx2") == 0) x = fx2;
    if (strcmp(y, "fx3") == 0) x = fx3;
    if (x) printf("%d\n", x(42)); // chama fx1(42) ou fx2(42) ou fx3(42) */
    return 0;
}
```

Podes ver [o codigo a funcionar no ideone](http://ideone.com/aER4t7).

Comment: Entendi o que você fez. Mas eu não quero ter que fazer comparações, verificando se y é tal função. Estou partindo do pressuposto que eu não conheço os nomes das funções, somente a string em y.